# How to get links to open correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mern

I have a element on my website that get links from a form. I fetch the data and put it in a div. One of the fields of data is a link to the person's website. I have it so that when someone clicks on the div it open up the link. But when it fetches the link it adds it along the current domain. For example,

Link: example.com

Domain: domain.com

what happens: domain.com/example.com

```html
<a href={`${props.person.person_link}`}>
    <div className="card-body">
<a/>
```

Comment: The URL needs to include the protocol.  http:// or https://

Comment: @DanielBeck or to use the current a simplified `//${person_link}`

Comment: Yep, that works too